# GWT Canvas painting on server side?

Tags: gwt, canvas, png

for my GWT app i am tranferring Data to the client which is using the data to draw on a canvas. The Problem is that the tranfer of this data consumes too much bandwidth.

My question is: could I create a png file in a similar way on the server and just send it to the Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that should be no problem. 
There are two ways to solve it.

1. If you just want to display the image: Create a `IMG` widget and set the src to a server url which generates the PNG. (`<img src="http://myHost/loadImage?id=12">`
2. If you want to work with the image: Use `RequestBuilder` to transfer the PNG to the client. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071884/gwt-base64-image) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553316/gwt-image-from-database) for more details.

**Update**: 
For the backend side there are also different solutions:

1. [Server-side node canvas](https://www.learnboost.com/blog/introducing-node-canvas-server-side-html5-canvas-api/)
2. Use JAVA libraries to generate PNGs (see [here](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-05-2000/jw-0505-servlets.html) for more details)

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your reply! I guess the AWT graphics class suits exactly what I need. Lets see if I can make good use of it...